# Ion-slides not displayed correctly on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I’m trying to upload my app to App Store, but in some iOS devices the ion-slides does not shown correctly.

It seems that the problem is the IOS version.

Bad - iPad 9th Gen (iOS 15.0)
iPad (9th generation)
iPad (9th generation)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPpr4.jpg)
Bad - iPad Air 4th Gen (iOS 15.0)
iPad Air (4th generation)
iPad Air (4th generation)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsoFV.jpg)
Ok - iPadPro 11-inch (iOS 12.4)
iPadPro 11-Inch 12.4
iPadPro 11-Inch 12.4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCTB6.jpg)
Anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `ion-slides` never worked 100% good. I had to remove it from some projects and it never behaved as supposed (specially in iOS). In fact, ionic is deprecating it for version 6:

> With the release of Ionic Framework v6, the Ionic Team has deprecated
> the ion-slides and ion-slide components in favor of using the official
> framework integrations provided by Swiper.

(Quote from https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides)

I would recommend you to move to [swipperjs](https://swiperjs.com/) (which is in fact what runs under `ion-slides`). Is a lot of work, but way less than trying to tame `ion-slides`.

Good luck!